# codeigniter www subdomain issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I have strange issue with codeigniter and www subdomain.

When i load http://foobar.com the page opens normally but when i load http://www.foobar.com I get CodeIgniter's 404 message

Here is the content of .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: might be issue on your server side, not in CI itself, www subdomain is not pointing into correct place

Comment: Vlakarados The settings are the default ones. I did not change anything in the file.

Comment: @Serg no, if it's a CodeIgniter's 404 it most probably points to the right place.

Comment: ok, if you are using virtual hosting, what is that? or maybe you are running nginx?

Comment: i'm using dedicated server with apache installed

Comment: so there is problem with you domain redirest.. you can chec it

Answer (score 0):

Some settings treat the subdomain as a folder inside the root. perhaps it tries to load the codeigniter url `www`? Troubleshoot with `$route['404_override']`

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

create a controller and point to that controller, and inside the controller's function, run

`print_r($this->router)` and `echo $this->uri->uri_string()`

Hopefully this may help you understand what's going on